# Cone is not of class C1

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry

Show that the cone given by $C = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\}$ is not a 2 dimensional surface of class C1.

I am confused to what I need to prove. I know how to show that C is not differentiable at (0, 0), is that enough to show it is not of C1? Or do I have to show it is not a smooth surface?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is enough to show $C$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$. More precisely, check for any chart of the $C$, transition map $\varphi\circ\psi^{-1}:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is not $C^1$, where $(0,0,0)\in\text{dom}(\varphi),\text{dom}(\psi)$.

Comment: 1) so to my understanding C1 is just continuously differentiable, smooth is it is of class $C \infty$? 
2) if so, I do not really understand what a regular surface is; is regular equal to smooth surface? I read the definition but am very confused

Comment: 1) $C^1$ function and smooth ($C^\infty$) function refers to continuously differentiable function, and infinitely continuously differentiable function, respectively. When you mean $C^1$ and smooth manifold, the definition is different, but involving notion of $C^1$ functions and smooth ($C^\infty$) functions. Read the definition again and again. Simply put, $C^k$ manifold is a topological manifold with an atlas whose transition maps are all k-times continuously differentiable. 2) Yes. They are same.